# Enter Key Going To The Next Frame in Flash CS3 and Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs3

In flash CS3 i have three frames and when i press enter from frame one it goes to next frame. But i want to stop that in my project. Like when user press enter key in the frame one it should not go to frame 2. How to do this in Action Script 3.0 using Flash CS3?

Answer (score 2):

Is this really in the published SWF or just in the Flash IDE? Hitting the ENTER key in Flash plays the timeline.

**This happens only when you hit ENTER while looking at the SWF in Flash. Try opening it in the file system.**

[image]

If not you should look into KeyboardEvents:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUpHandler);

private function onKeyUpHandler(event : KeyboardEvent) : void
{
    switch(event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.ENTER:
            nextFrame();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then just use the method nextFrame()

Comment: I want this to be done in published SWF. I tried your above lines of script. Its not working.

Comment: updated my answer! This happens only when you hit ENTER while looking at the SWF in Flash. Try opening it in the file system.

Comment: +1 for a nicely formatted answer. I'm thought that disable keyboard shortcuts included the Enter key (haven't checked).

Answer (score 0):

When you test your movie. Instead of just hitting cmd-enter, hit cmd-f12 this will test it in a browser which will eliminate flash's default enter key functionality.